# trying to make a self-modifying function

Tags: functions, list

I'm trying to make a function that returns a list of [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number):

> A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors

For instance, 28 is perfect because its factors are 1, 2, 4, 7, 14 and 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28.

My initial code was:

```lisp
(defun factors (n)
  "Return a list of the factors of N, except N itself."
  (let ((factors (list 1))
        (i 2))
    (while (<= i (/ n 2))
      (if (zerop (% n i))
          (setq factors (cons i factors)))
      (setq i (1+ i)))
    factors))

(defun is-perfect (n)
  "Return `t` is N is a perfect number, `nil` otherwise."
  (and (/= 1 n)
       (let* ((factors (factors n))
              (factors-sum (seq-reduce '+ factors 0)))
         (= n factors-sum))))

(defun perfect-numbers (n)
  "Return the perfect numbers smaller than or equal to N."
    (seq-filter 'is-perfect (number-sequence 2 n)))
```

It works, but gets noticeably slow for 10000. Remembering that I [recently had trouble with a self modifying function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/why-does-this-function-keep-updating-the-same-result) I thought I'd try to exploit this to optimize `perfect-numbers`. The idea is to keep the list of the perfect numbers we already computed. I tried this:

```lisp
(defun perfect-numbers (n)
  "Return the perfect numbers smaller than or equal to N."
  (let* ((perfect-numbers '(6)) ; my hope was that this list would get updated each time I call the function
         (highest (car (last perfect-numbers)))
         (new-perfect-numbers (seq-filter 'is-perfect (number-sequence (1+ highest) n))))
    (setq perfect-numbers (append perfect-numbers new-perfect-numbers))
    (seq-filter (apply-partially '>= n) perfect-numbers)))
```

However in this case, `perfect-numbers` does not seems to be updated, and I don't understand why:

```
ELISP> (perfect-numbers 1000)
(6 28 496)
ELISP> (symbol-function 'perfect-numbers)
(lambda
  (n)
  "Return the perfect numbers smaller than or equal to N."
  (let*
      ((perfect-numbers
        '(6)) ; the list did not get updated :(
       (highest
        (car
         (last perfect-numbers)))
       (new-perfect-numbers
        (seq-filter 'is-perfect
                    (number-sequence
                     (1+ highest)
                     n))))
    (setq perfect-numbers
          (append perfect-numbers new-perfect-numbers))
    (seq-filter
     (apply-partially '>= n)
     perfect-numbers)))
```

Comment: Little-known fact: "self-modifying code" is a synonym for "maddening to debug". Better use explicit memoization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you modify the variable binding, not the data structure.
[`append`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html) creates a *fresh* list, while [`nconc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html#Rearrangement) modifies its argument.
Replace `(setq perfect-numbers (append perfect-numbers new-perfect-numbers))` with `(nconc perfect-numbers new-perfect-numbers)` and you will get the behavior you think you want.

I must advise against this though because

1. [modifying quoted lists is not a good idea](http://clhs.lisp.se/Issues/iss083_w.htm).
2. You have to seed your variable with `(6)` which is poor style.

I suggest a more standard way to encapsulate the data (see [Lexical-Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html)):

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(let ((perfect-numbers ()))
  (defun perfect-numbers (n)
    "Return the perfect numbers smaller than or equal to N."
    (let ((new-perfect-numbers
           (seq-filter 'is-perfect (number-sequence
                                    (if perfect-numbers
                                        (1+ (car (last perfect-numbers)))
                                        2)
                                    n))))
      (setq perfect-numbers (append perfect-numbers new-perfect-numbers))
      (seq-filter (apply-partially '>= n) perfect-numbers))))
```

Now `(perfect-numbers 100)` returns `(6 28)` as expected.

Comment: Thank you, `nconc` does solve the problem. However the better solution you provide does not work for me, I get `*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s value as variable is void: perfect-numbers`. I did set `lexical-binding` to `t` in `ielm`.

Comment: Oh, it works if I copy paste the code in the interpreter actually, but not if I put it in my source file and then do `C-x C-e` or `M-x eval-buffer`.

Comment: Nevermind: things work well if I do `M-: (setq lexical-binding t)`, and then re-evaluate the form. Setting it only in `ielm` does not seem to work.

Comment: My understanding is that having `;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-` as a file-local variable in the library which defines your function is the only *dependable* way to enable lexical binding.  (Although `ielm` and `M-:` and `*scratch*` will default to lexical binding [starting from Emacs 27](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/etc/NEWS?id=e08e0880f9892fba747abdb95b1f3382ebd17e32).)